# How do you run heroku toolbar

Tags: facebook, heroku

I have just downloaded the Heroku Toolbelt yet I can see nothing on my PC or in the Program files directory that indicates how to run the toolbelt. Also Facebook now require secure browsing yet I don't want to pay for a SSL certificate as my apps are for learning code only.
I would be very grateful if someone could explain how I run the toolbelt - last time I installed it it seemed ok. Also how does Heroku know which app I am uploading?

Answer (score 1):

Well the toolbelt is a command line interface so you need to start a command prompt.

To run the toolbelt (in windows 7 or with the "[Open Command Prompt From Here](http://www.petri.co.il/add_command_prompt_here_shortcut_to_windows_explorer.htm)" Microsoft Powertoys) create an empty folder, the holding Shift + Right Mouse Click, select "Open Command Window Here".  Then (assuming the toolbelt is installed in your Path) run

```
heroku login
```

and then

```
heroku create
```

This will create a working directory to code.  When you run `git push heroku master` it will send your working code to your instance.  Read [this guide](http://www.petri.co.il/add_command_prompt_here_shortcut_to_windows_explorer.htm) for more advnaced usage.

As for your 3rd question, it knows based on the current directory you are in when you run it.  I wouldn't consider the 2nd question related to the other 2 so if you want a clear answer to it I would suggest posing it as a separate question.